# How can I decode ssl traffic generated by apache-httpclient?

Tags: java, ssl, wireshark, apache-httpclient-4.x

When using firefox I know that I can set the SSLKEYLOGFILE envvar, 
and then provide the path to wireshark to decrypt the ssl traffic.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format)

Is there a way to decrypt ssl traffic when requests are generated by apache httpclient?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to decrypt data transferred on the wire, or you just want to see composition of HTTP packets?

Comment: My problem that I want to compare requests performed in the browser with requests sent by my app. More specific: I think there is a tiny difference that prevents my back-end code to issue a facebook token after login, and I want to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running HttpClient with wire logging turned on as described [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html). This should be enough to see the exact composition of HTTP packets transferred over the wire.

Comment: seems like the link you provided is dead.